# how can i compile my stored procedures in production server

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, dll, compilation, locking

How can I encrypt or compile all my stored procedures in the production server?

I can remember in MCDBA 2003 we had things like CLR samples and we can compile and use SP as dll.

Today I search on google and can't find any solution.

Are there any good solutions for this?

How many ways to do this?

Is there any ci-cd way to convert and install them in the production server?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope it may be help you. If you want, you look this web-site. (https://database.guide/how-to-encrypt-a-stored-procedure-in-sql-server/)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure the impact on the performance of stored procedures but I used for views and it didn't impact its performance.